# Problem with Scripting a baking procedure

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

Im am importing alot of models with alot of materials attached. Therefore i wish to bake all of these into a single texture with a python script. I have a alot of trouble with the baking of textures.

It seems as if there is something wrong with selection and saving of the image i make and bake onto. I hope someone can help.

First i have some  code that rotate and translate my object then in the next stage i want to

1. uv-unwrap.
2. create a new image with a id name
3. bake textures onto this uv map
4. save the image on harddrive
5. delete all material
6. make a new material
7. assign a new texture to it
8. choose the bake texture from harddrive
9. set to uv map.

This is my code so fare. Im using blender 2.79

```
# Smart UV map project 
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()


# create an image which will store the baked data
image = bpy.data.images.new("ElementName", bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x, bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y, alpha = 0)

bpy.data.images["ElementName"].use_fake_user = True
#bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
#bpy.ops.image.open(filepath = "C:\\\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\ElementName.png", directory="C:\\\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\", files=[{"name":"ElementName.png", "name":"ElementName.png"}], show_multiview=False)

bpy.data.screens['UV Editing'].areas[1].spaces[0].image = image

bpy.context.scene.render.bake_type = 'TEXTURE'
image = bpy.ops.object.bake_image()

image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.filepath = 'C:\\\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\ElementName.png'
image.save()

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

for x in range(len(ctx.material_slots)): 
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
if mat is None:
    # create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    # assign to 1st material slot
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    # no slots
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)   


bpy.data.materials["Material"].use_face_texture = True

bpy.ops.texture.new()
bpy.ops.image.open(filepath = "C:\\\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\ElementName.png", directory="\\\\beumer.com\\public\\HomeDirs\\Sub\\Denmark\\AAR1\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\", files=[{"name":"ElementName.png", "name":"ElementName.png"}], show_multiview=False)

# save blender file somewhere. Here just D drive. 
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="D:\\\\pysaved.blend")
```